# Different homology groups for same space? (cellular homology of the 3-Torus ($T^3$))

Tags: algebraic-topology

I had an exercise to find a CW-structure on $T^3$ = $S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1$. And i thought that i have found one (i thought about $T^3$ as the regular polygon with 12 sides with points identified):

- one $0$-cell
- six $1$-cells
- one $2$-cell (interior of the polygon)

And i got the homology groups:

- $\mathbb Z$ (degree $0$)
- $\mathbb Z^6$ (degree $1$)
- $\mathbb Z$ (degree $2$)
- $0$ in all other degrees

In the solutions they got something different. They did the same thing as in Hatcher , page 142, Example 2.39 ([https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf))

Obviously it's not possible to get different homology groups for the same space, right? But i also can't see how my solution is wrong, does someone see it?

Comment: Your proposed CW-structure isn't correct. What you have written does not even define a $3$-manifold. I think you should study the cellular structure Hatcher gives in the example you reference.

Comment: I think your CW-complex is a genus 3 surface, but I am not entirely sure.

Comment: hm, okay. we always defined the n-Torus like i did, but maybe they meant the "solid" torus in this exercise.

Comment: I think you're confusing 'surface with $n$ holes' and 'product of $n$ circles'. The latter is an $n$-manifold.

Comment: $T^3$ must have one or more $3$-cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are confusing 'product of $3$ circles' with 'surface with $3$ holes'. The former is a $3$-manifold, but your proposed CW-structure has no 3-cell.

Hatcher's cellular structure on $T^3$ in the example you reference is standard.